# Discrete Math Combinatorics, permutation, one-to-one proof

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

I am having trouble getting started with the following proof: *(This is homework, so I'd appreciate a nudge in the right direction.)*

Let *m*, *r* $\in$ N with 0 $\leq$ *r* $\leq$ *m*. Prove that the number of one-to-one functions from *A* to *B*, where *n(A) = r* and *n(B)=m* is

$\frac{m!}{(m - r)!}$

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Note that

$$\frac{m!}{(m-r)!}=\underbrace{m(m-1)(m-2)\ldots(m-r+1)}_{r\text{ factors}}\;.$$

Let $A=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_r\}$. Imagine building a one-to-one function from $A$ to $B$ by assigning the values $f(a_1),f(a_2),\ldots,f(a_r)$ one at a time. Use the multiplication principle (sometimes called the Chinese menu principle) to count the different ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

**Some hints**

Let $A = \{a_1,a_2,...,a_r\}$ and $B = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_n \}$.

A one-to-one function $f$ assigns each element $a_i$ of $A$ a distinct element $b_j = f (a_i)$ of $B$;

- For $a_1$ there are $m$ choices for $f(a_1)$
- For $a_2$ there are $m−1$ choices for $f(a_2)$
- $\cdots$
- For $a_n$ there are $(m−(n−1))$ choices.

and you can conclude